# Search a text between many files in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix, testing, jestjs

Using jest with node, I want to check if one of my files has a bad resolved GIT conflict. I did a code that works in my machine:

```js
const cmd = `find . -not \\( -path ./node_modules -prune \\) -not \\( -path ./.next -prune \\) -not \\( -path ./.git -prune \\) -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -li "<<<< HEAD"`

describe('Git conflicts', () => {
  test('All conflicts should be resolved', () => {
    const result = require('child_process')
      .execSync(cmd)
      .toString('utf8')
    expect(result).toBe('./server/__tests__/check-git-conflicts.test.js\n')
  })
})
```

However, as I said, it works in my machine... But it doesn't work in different environments because I'm executing directly a UNIX command.

In order to do it more robust. I want to change that command:

```
find . -not \\( -path ./node_modules -prune \\) -not \\( -path ./.next -prune \\) -not \\( -path ./.git -prune \\) -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -li "<<<< HEAD
```

To write it in just `node.js` code to be more compatible with environments. I tried to use `fs.readFile`, but I failed in my try...

Does anybody know an efficient way in Node.js to search a text in many files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in this way:

```js
const fs = require('fs')

const toIgnore = [
  'node_modules',
  '.next',
  '.git',
  'check-git-conflicts.test.js',
]

function getFilesWithSomeConflict(dir, files_) {
  files_ = files_ || []

  fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {
    const name = dir + '/' + file
    if (toIgnore.includes(file)) return
    if (fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()) {
      getFilesWithSomeConflict(name, files_)
      return
    }
    if (fs.readFileSync(name).includes('<<<< HEAD')) {
      files_.push(name)
    }
  })

  return files_
}

describe('Git conflicts', () => {
  test('All conflicts should be resolved', () => {
    const result = getFilesWithSomeConflict('.')
    expect(result).toHaveLength(0)
  })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Use "process.platform" and store OS information in a variable. Set command based on running OS.
For example:

```
var os = process.platform
const cmd = ""
if(os==="linux")
const cmd = `find . -not \\( -path ./node_modules -prune \\) -not \\( -path ./.next -prune \\) -not \\( -path ./.git -prune \\) -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -li "<<<< HEAD"
```

Comment: No, this is just what I don't want... For example depend the Linux it can work or not depending if xargs, grep are installed... I'm looking for a solution in Node.js without executing any command.